# Warning: Could not find ptimapfiles.map and other errors

Tags: fonts, errors

Good morning. When I open my PCTex Professional software, the typesetter bar at the bottom states:

> Warning: could not find ptimapfiles.map
>
> Warning: could not find mapfiles.map

When I go to typeset the document, the pdf file renders the fonts incorrectly and all of the spacing is incorrect.  I'm not sure what to do to fix this.  I tried restarting the program as well as the computer and it does not help.  I'm fairly new to this program and not sure how to make this go away.  Is there someone that can help me?

EDIT:  a second issue is now occuring.  I was recently sent a file from my professor to edit and now, when I typset, the PDF will not open for that file.  I've emailed support@pctex.com but no one has responded.  What should I do

Comment: So it out that my SpyHunter malware program was running automatically at the onset of the computer being turned on.  Somehow that was causing the issue.  Thanks all!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  solved by the OP as indicated in his/her comment.